# Could not cast NSDicationry with NSData in WebService call request

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, response, codable

Trying to wrap Codable response data from WebService
used cocoa pod
pod 'WebService', '~> 0.4'

```
var webServiceObject : WebService = WebService()

webServiceObject.sendRequest(URLString, parameters: parameters as NSDictionary?, requestType: .post,  success: {response,data in
            
    do{
    // Handle data when request Success
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    
                let result = try jsonDecoder.decode([ResponseModelValue].self, from: data as! Data)
                    print(response?.statusCode as Any)
                   print("Success Response Value", result)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
             }
            }, failed: {
                (response : HTTPURLResponse?, ResponseDict : Any?) in
                print(response?.statusCode as Any)

                print("Failed Response Dictionary", ResponseDict!)
            
                // Handle data when request fails
                
            }, encoded: false )
```

I got following error

**Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x10c81ab38) to 'NSData' (0x10c819620).**

Can any one suggest me what I done wrong here,  so I can parse proper response data with codable `[ResponseModelValue]`

Answer (score 0):

After looking at that library, it appears that it will turn the response into a dictionary if possible and fall back to returning data.
https://github.com/kansaraprateek/WebService/blob/master/WebService/Classes/WebService.swift#L281

It doesn't appear like there is a way to configure that behaviour. The library was also created before `Codable` was created. You may need to reach out the library owner for a fix, fork the repo and fix it yourself, or switch to using URLSession since the code you posted is mostly the same as a URLSession call.